# Three related models in inlineformset_factory django

Tags: django, forms, inline-formset

help please.
I have three models:

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_('Title'))
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Slug'))
    summary = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Summary'))

class SecondModel(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(FirstModel)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(ThirdModel)
    value = models.CharField(_('Value'), max_length=255)

class ThirdModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('ThirdModel'), max_length=100)
    validation = models.CharField(_('Value type'), choices=CHOICESTUPLE)
```

And i want render two forms with FirstModel and ThirdModel in one template
using inlineformset_factory() with UpdateView. How to correctly create two formsets with this relationship between models. Is it possible?